# OpenGL drawing with mouse

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, opengl

If I try to texture drawing line with loaded texture

```
glLineWidth(10);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTextura);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(location.x, location.y);
glVertex2f(prevLocation.x, prevLocation.y);
glEnd();
glFlush();
glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

It draws nothing. When I use same code, but drawing not GL_LINES, but GL_POINTS everything works as it should work. [Image link here](http://s16.postimage.org/sdbzgpzir/Screen_Shot_2012_06_26_at_3_10_35_PM.png).

If i don't use texture here, and use GL_LINES, it draws lines as it should, but its not looking good. [Image link here](http://s16.postimage.org/fkja31yj7/Screen_Shot_2012_06_26_at_3_01_50_PM.png). Any solutions for drawing nice, smooth textured lines?

Answer (score 2):

A line will not "magically" use the texture as kind of a brush applied along the path of the line. You'd actually have to supply some texture coordinates, but those would then only take slices out of the texture and not apply it as a "brush".

If points work for you, only if point sprites are enabled, because a point would sample only a single texure pixel and spread it over its whole area.

Honestly, I think your whole attempt is flawed. Usually when drawing with brushed, you draw it as a large number of textured quads at a regular, small distance.

Comment: So what solution would you suggest for me to make openGL brush? Everything is working good, just need somehow to make it look like brush :) Can you point me to any useful information?

Comment: @hockeyman: Well. First I suggest you don't confuse OpenGL with some sort of graphics toolkit. It's mostly meant for drawing dynamic realtime graphics. And what I suggest I already wrote in my answer: A dense line of closely distanced quads, textured with the brush texture. That's also how Photoshop and similar programs work (only they don't use OpenGL for drawing operations).

Comment: Actually openGL here is used for drawing on high resolution images with no LAG. The OpenGL faster because everything is happening in GPU. Try to implement brush without OpenGL and you will understand why it is needed. Actually you are wrong when you tell, that Photoshop is not using OpenGL.

Comment: No he is right. Almost everything you said in this last comment is wrong.

Comment: Try it your self and you will see, that brush without OpenGL is very slow.

Comment: @hockeyman: Well I wonder how Photoshop did implement brushes without OpenGL acceleration some 15 years ago. Actually there's no single professional grade image manipulation program that would do its drawing operations in OpenGL. For one single reason: The OpenGL specification is not pixel exact. If you carry out the same sequence of operations on two different OpenGL implementations the results may vary a lot.

Comment: I have tried it - on various occasions. If drawing a line on the screen is slowing down your program I think you have bigger issues.

Comment: @hockeyman: And no, implementing a brush purely in software is not slow, if you know how to do such things efficiently. The key subject here is implementing cache friendly algorithms, so that your inner loop in the brush application will not stall on memory read/writes.